# Why can't I deserialize value of date in Jackson?

Tags: java, jackson

Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.Date` from String "2021-04-20T07:49:18.19Z": expected format "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSZ"

The pattern seems to be fine for both serialize and deserialize objects.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    DeserializedObject deserializedObject = objectMapper.readValue(
        "{\n" +
            "\"date\": \"2021-04-20T07:49:18.19Z\"\n" +
        "}",
        DeserializedObject.class);
}


static class DeserializedObject {

    @JsonProperty("date")
    private Date date;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the right pattern for "2021-04-20T07:49:18.19Z" is "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'" you can retry this

then put a JsonFormat on the field

@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
private Date date;